# Magento CE upgrade from 1.9.3.6 to 1.9.3.10 always results in the 1.9.3.6

Tags: magento, ssh, upgrade, magento-1.9

I'm trying to upgrade magento from  from 1.9.3.6 to 1.9.3.10 but I always results in the 1.9.3.6 version.

I'm using following commands:

```
cd ~/public
chmod 750 mage
./mage mage-setup .
./mage config-set preferred_state stable
./mage sync
./mage install https://connect20.magentocommerce.com/community Mage_All_Latest --force
php shell/indexer.php reindexall
rm -rf downloader/.cache/ var/cache/
```

then as a result I'm getting:

```
nstalling package community/Lib_ZF_Locale 1.12.10.11
Package community/Lib_ZF_Locale 1.12.10.11 installed successfully
Package installed: community/Interface_Adminhtml_Default 1.9.3.6
Package installed: community/Interface_Frontend_Default 1.9.3.6
Package installed: community/Interface_Install_Default 1.9.3.6
Package installed: community/Mage_Downloader 1.9.3.6
Package installed: community/Mage_Centinel 1.9.3.6
Package installed: community/Interface_Frontend_Base_Default 1.9.3.6
Package installed: community/Phoenix_Moneybookers 1.9.3.6
Package installed: community/Mage_Compiler 1.9.3.6
Package installed: community/Magento_Mobile 1.9.3.6
Package installed: community/Lib_Cm 1.9.3.6
Package installed: community/Cm_RedisSession 1.9.3.6
Package installed: community/Interface_Frontend_Rwd_Default 1.9.3.6
Package installed: community/Mage_Core_Adminhtml 1.9.3.6
Package installed: community/Mage_Core_Modules 1.9.3.6
Package installed: community/Lib_Js_Ext 1.9.3.6
Package installed: community/Lib_LinLibertineFont 2.8.14.12
Package installed: community/Lib_Js_TinyMCE 3.5.11.11
Package installed: community/Lib_Varien 1.9.3.6
Package installed: community/Lib_Google_Checkout 1.9.3.6
Package installed: community/Lib_Js_Calendar 1.51.1.12
Package installed: community/Lib_Js_Mage 1.9.3.6
Package installed: community/Lib_Phpseclib 1.9.3.6
Package installed: community/Mage_Locale_en_US 1.9.3.6
Package installed: community/Lib_Mage 1.9.3.6
Package installed: community/Lib_Magento 1.9.3.6
Package installed: community/Lib_Credis 1.9.3.6
Package installed: community/Lib_Pelago 1.9.3.6
Package installed: community/Lib_Unserialize 1.9.3.6
Package installed: community/Lib_IDNA2 1.9.3.6
Package installed: community/Lib_ZF 1.12.10.11
Package installed: community/Lib_Js_Prototype 1.9.3.6
Package installed: community/Lib_ZF_Locale 1.12.10.11
```

I also tried upgrading from file, that I got here: [https://magento.com/tech-resources/download][1] but then I get an error that install-file: Package file is invalid. Did anyone else have this issue? How can it be solved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hi I finally got to the solution. 
Here is the correct sequence:

```
cd ~/public
chmod 750 mage
./mage config-set preferred_state stable
./mage list-upgrades
./mage upgrade-all --force
```

Once the update is completed, we should use this command to make database upgrade:

```
php -f ./index.php
```

Finally there are couple more commands that should be run:

```
grep -rZl ‘0660’ . | xargs -0 -l sed -i -e ‘s/0660/0644/g’
grep -rZl ‘0770’ . | xargs -0 -l sed -i -e ‘s/0770/0755/g’
find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \; && find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
```

Finish it up  by cleaning cache:

```
rm -rf var/cache
```